# How to break down the sentence この薬は世界で１４万人に使うぐらい用意される予定です?

Tags: grammar

I've been looking at this sentence for a long time and can't get what the grammar tells me in this case.

> この薬は世界で１４万人に使うぐらい用意される予定です

Could someone break this sentence down for me?
I appreciate your answers beforehand.

Comment: There is a typo around 使. Could you fix it, or does the original sentence already have this error?

Comment: 使う. I accidentally removed the う

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the Japanese stack exchange. Unfortunately we are not a bulk translation service and so won't be able to answer questions for you unless you can provide some evidence of research and some guesses about what this might mean, or what parts in particular you are struggling with. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: My guess is the medicine plans to make the 140000 people prepare for using the medicine worldwide

Comment: The medicine does the planning? That's how you understood it?

Comment: Makes sense to me, because the topic marker is coming after 薬

Comment: Actually the 140,000 people do rhe preparation right?

Comment: No, the 140,000 are not doing the preparation. It might help if you could edit your question to include your own attempt at a translation, or at least some indication of what you think the sentence means. (See rebuuilt's comment above.)

Comment: I think I understand it now。It's passive (される), so that means it was arranged by an unmentioned (probably the world government) human or group of people. That means as a conclusion the 140,000 using the new drug in this world is planned to be prepared by someone unknown (still prolly the world government)

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure of the sentence is as follows:

> この薬は用意される予定です
>   (literally) Concerning this medicine, it's planned to be prepared.

Of course, it's a drug company (not patients or the drug itself) that will actually manufacture this medicine.

～ぐらい forms an adverbial phrase that means "to the point where ～". For example:

- びっくりするぐらい美味しい
  It is delicious to the point where I'm surprised.
  → It's surprisingly delicious.
- 目に見えないぐらい小さい
  It is small to the point where it is invisible to your eyes.
  → It is too small to see.

世界で14万人に使うぐらい literally means "to the point where [people] use (the medicine) for 140,000 people in the world". In this context, it can be rephrased to "(manufactured) enough to treat 140,000 patients in the world".

> この薬は世界で14万人に使うぐらい用意される予定です。
>   The medicine will be prepared for use in 140,000 patients in the world.